# Datos de pestaña actual datatable

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, jsp

Lo que estoy haciendo es usar el Plugin datatables.net para trabajar mis tablas, sobre los datos que cargo en la tabla necesito pasarlos a un web services, y luego dependiendo del resultado mando a pintar algo en la tabla.

Luego del contexto lo que necesito saber es de lo que trato de hacer...

Al momento de mostrar los datos en la tabla se muestran 10 primero y en la segunda paginación otros 10 y si hay una tercera otros 10 hasta tener todos los registros en la tabla;.

El servicio se debe corre sobre los 30 o N números de registro porque recorro la data de la tabla completa con un array que llene anteriormente, lo que quiero es saber si puedo acceder a la data que se esta mostrando en ese momento es decir los 10 datos de la paginación uno, y al pasar a la segunda cargar esos otros 10.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').dataTable({
        "drawCallback": function (settings) {
            for (var i = 0; i < miArray.length; i++) {
                reten(miArray[i]);
                consultatc(miArray[i]);
            }                          
        }                      
    });                                        
});
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con pestaña? Si se trata de algún script para crear secciones en la página, agrega el código con el que creas y manipulas las pestañas, de lo contrario no hay forma de ayudarte.

Comment: creo que debe explicar mejor lo que estas intentando hacer, el resultado que tienes y el que esperas tener.

Comment: tambien te recomiendo que pases a la lecturas de los siguientes artículos: 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example y 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic y 
https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: ya esta editada la pregunta

Comment: será el plugin datatable.net?

Comment: pestaña  es en realidad lo números de paginación?

Comment: si es el plugin datatables

Comment: cuando te refieres a cargar los datos de las 10 registro al cambiar de paginación no termino de entender el objetivo ... tienes algo mas de código tambien donde lo que espliques lo hayas intentado hacer?? o estas suponiendo que debemos hacerlo nosotros, por que de poder todo se puede en programación, menos hacer gente XD.

Comment: con datatables se carga los datos digamos ejemplo 100, entonces datatables te divide la data por 10 pestañas de 10 datos cada una, que vas cambiando con el boton de paginacion, con el codigo de arriba corro dos servicios despues de que se ejecuta la tabla y cada vez que se presiona el boton de paginacion pero de los 100 registros que estan en las 10 pestañas, yo solo quisiera saber si podria obtener un array con los 10 datos que se estan viendo en este momento

Comment: si el evento de cambio de pagina seria: page mira la documentación: https://datatables.net/reference/event/page pero esto tienes que combinarlo con:  page.info() aquí esta la documentación: https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.info()